# Flutter face id loca auth

Tags: ios, flutter, face-id, localauthentication

I am new in flutter, i try to develop face id auth using flutter (3.0.5) and local_auth: ^2.1.2,
but on ios it show error **"@import local_auth" not found.**

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your project terminal.

`cd ios`
`pod reintegrate`
`pod install`
`cd ..`
`flutter pub get`

Then try running the app.